Can't connect to database in mysql (mysql c++ connector) [Linux]
I have downloaded the c++ mysql connector (version: 8.3.0) from here: mysql connector c++
I also installed the library in linux: libmysqlcppconn-dev
I installed xampp. I can access to phpmyadmin via localhost and I can access to mysql : sudo mysql -u root -p
I gave a password to the user root and flushed the priveleges.
I have this example code:
/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "the_password");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
     << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

But i have this error:
# ERR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (MySQL error code: 1045, SQLState: 28000 )

Actually, what i really want is to connect with an user called admin, but i can not do:  sudo mysql -u admin -p because i have the error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .However admin has all the priveles and it has assigned the host localhost.
Another way to connect is:
mysqlx::Session session("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "the password");
mysqlx::Schema schema = session.getSchema("test");

But It can't connect too.
How can i do it?
Thanks in advance

Note that the mysql client by default connects to a UNIX socket, not the TCP address you specify in your code. This is not a code problem until mysql -u admin -h 127.0.0.1 -p works and the corresponding C++ code does not. Also note that running mysql under sudo is useless.

Hi, yes mysql connects to the socket, i just did the test to know if the user is valid. If I try mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p i have the error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Ok, i saw this link: link and if i put the address 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it connects

which use has the privileges and password admin@localhost or admin@127.0.0.1 ?

just to make querys like update, select, insert in a database

i saw this link: MYSQL user and if i put the address 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, it connects
